# como puedo generar dinamicamente componentes de ionic?

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Digamos si tengo un campo de texto e ingreso un 5 se generen 5 botones o si luego ingreso un 7  se generen 7 botones

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es un tema único de Ionic, realmente lo que planteas es jugar con el DOM de la página renderizada por Ionic, creo que en este sentido pueden haber varias formas de hacerlo, pero  me limitare a la siguiente opción que se me ocurre y a lo mejor es la más practica, es que crees una lista con los datos del botón y luego en la vista usando **ngFor* imprimas tantos botones como tenga la lista. Por ej:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of botones">
    <button (click)="accion(item.accion)">{{item.nombre}}</button>
</div>
```

Si la lista comienza vacía en principio no habrían botones en la ventana. A medida que la lista crezca aparecerían.